# Execute MapReduce job only on a part of a HDFS file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a big file in HDFS (~20Gb) on which I usually execute a MapReduce job. Around 170 mappers are created. The `InputFormat` used is a `FileInputFormat`.

Now I would like to execute the MapReduce job only on a part of the file (for example, the first 40Mb of the file).

Is there a simple way to perform this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

​Hello all,

Finally, I found a solution consisting of deriving the `FileInputFormat` class and overriding the `getSplits` method in order to get only the splits corresponding to the wanted part of the HDFS file.

In this method, I call the super class to get the splits generated by the `InputFileFormat` class. Thanks to the configuration of the job, I manage to get some information like the beginning of the HDFS file and the end of the HDFS file I wanted to read. Finally, the beginning and the end of all splits get from the `getSPlits` method of the super class are compared to the previous information and returned if they match the the wanted part of the HDFS file.

Comment: Please check the in-built TextInputFormat , KeyValueInputFormat.  I believe you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi @KrazyGautam, the TextInputFormat is not what I need in my case because I processes binary file.